# Stack dynamically added images using absolute positioning and z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array of images, and I would like to have them stacked on top of each other. Each of which will have `position: absolute` , `top: 0` , `left:0` and `z-index` in decreasing order by value. Only the image with the highest z-index value should be visible, all other images should be stacked below it.

Of course, the container div (`<div id="slide-container">`) will have `position: relative`

The only problem is, I am adding these images dynamically which might be the reason why I'm not getting the desired behavior.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide-container">

    <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>

    <!-- Here I will be adding the images  -->
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var slides = [
    {
        img: 'images/one.jpg',
        text: 'First Image' 
    },
    {
        img: 'images/two.jpg',
        text: 'Second Image'
    },
    {
        img: 'images/Three.jpg',
        text: 'Second Image'
    }
];

var z = slides.length;

for(var index = 0; index < slides.length; index++,z--){

    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', slides[index].img);
    img.attr('height','100%');
    img.attr('width','97%');
    img.attr('class','stock-images');

    // the following properties doesn't seem to have any effect.
    img.attr('position','absolute');
    img.attr('left','0');
    img.attr('top','0');
    img.attr('z-index',z);

    $('#slide-container').append(img);

}
```

**CSS**

```
#slide-container{
    /*border: 1px solid lightgrey;*/
    height: 32em;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center; /*not required if image takes 100% width of container*/

    position: relative; /*kept it relative positioned*/
}

.icon-container:nth-child(1){
    /*left arrow icon*/
    position: absolute;
    left: -4em;
    top: 45%;
    color: #DFE0E3;
}

.icon-container:nth-child(2){
    /*right arrow icon*/
    position: absolute;
    right: -4em;
    top: 45%;
    color: #DFE0E3;
}
```

I'm not getting the expected behavior, rather all the images are appearing one below the other. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: use `img.css` instead of `img.attr`.

Comment: could you create a fiddle

Comment: You are adding attributes to the tag, eg: `<img height="100%">`, to change the css you need to use `.css` instead of `.att`

Answer (score 1):

In your example the following code:

```
    var img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', slides[index].img);
    img.attr('height','100%');
    img.attr('width','97%');
    img.attr('class','stock-images');
```

creates in the HTML document the following tag:

```
<img src="img_path_from_array" height="100%" width="97%" class="stock-images">
```

But you want to edit the style/css of this element, so instead of using `.attr` you should use `.css` as follows:

```
img.attr('src', slides[index].img);
img.css('height','100%');
img.css('width','97%');
```

Make the distinction between HTML element's attribute, and HTML element's style attribute (css)

Comment: Thank you. I realized my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need jQuery to do everything

```
slides.forEach(function(slide, i) {
    var img = new Image
    img.src = slide.img
    img.className = 'stock-images'

    Object.assign(img.style, {
      height: '100%',
      width:  '100%',
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '0',
      top: '0',
      zIndex: i
    })

    $('#slide-container').append(img)
})
```